# How is it handled if the neighborhood of the image is outside the image?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, opticalflow

when using cv.calcOpticalFlowFarneback, how is it handled if the neighborhood of the image is outside the image? Maybe, I think that is padding, which is correct? Also Where can I refer to understand it?

Comment: Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  One question at a time please!

Comment: OpenCV's reference manual has a Bilbliography page, and it describes the source (paper) of `calcOpticalFlowFarneback` as [60].
I already forget details almostly... this method approximates local intensity field as simple formula(may be, 2nd order polynomial?). So, the result becomes locally smooth (looks likes as blurred). Google with keyword likes "polynomial expansion Farneback".

Comment: @fmw42 sorry, I rewrote my question and made more readble. sorry.

Comment: @fana Sorry for my bad English. I would like to know how is it handled if the neighborhood of the image is outside the image. I referd _"Two-Frame Motion Estimation Based on Polynomial Expansion"_ and **"it is generally a good idea to set the certainty to zero outside the image."** is written. But I don't know how this process is done in opencv. Do you know of any websites that I should refer to in order to understand the internal process?

Comment: Referring source code of OpenCV is most direct way?